# Underscore's Cloning of Mongoose Objects and Deleting Properties Not Working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, clone, mongoose, underscore.js

I'm using Mongoose and I want to remove the `_id` property from my Mongoose instance before I send the JSON response to the client.

Example:

```
var ui = _.clone(userInvite);
delete ui["_id"];
console.log(JSON.stringify(ui)); //still has "_id" property, why?
```

The previous didn't work.

However, if I do:

```
var ui = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userInvite)); //poor man's clone
delete ui["_id"];
console.log(JSON.stringify(ui)); //"_id" is gone! it works!
```

I don't understand why calling `delete` on a cloned object using Underscore doesn't work, but if I do the hacky JSON.string/JSON.parse, it works.

Any thoughts on this behavior?

Comment: Probably mongoose is trolling you and implementing `_id` as a getter/setter rather then as a property. Try `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(userInvite, "_id").get`

Comment: Modifying any properties of cloning mongoose object is impossible also.

Answer (score 6):

I just came across a similar issue trying to replace `_id` with `id`. Doing this worked for me:

```
Schema.methods.toJSON = function(options) {
  var document = this.toObject(options);
  document.id = document._id.toHexString();
  delete(document._id);
  return document;
};
```

Maybe it will start working if you replace `delete ui["_id"]` with `delete ui._id` or use `toObject` instead of `_.clone`.

Comment: I just ran into this trying to remove the password from my user object and was stumped for quite a while as to why 'delete user.password' was not working. Using toObject() on it seems to have done the trick. My guess is that mongoose isn't actually storing the attributes as properties on the object and builds it out dynamically using a toString method or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the previous answer, there is one more way to achieve the same. 'toObject' function applies transformation to the document which is defined by the schema.options.toObject.transform function, e.g

```
schema.options.toObject.transform = function(doc, ret) {
    ret.id = doc._id;
    delete ret._id;
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to lead to `TypeError: Cannot set property 'transform' of undefined`